# Import time/date with no seconds from csv

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to import from a csv file (which I cant change) into a mysql database dates and times that look like this in the `csv = 201210021015`

ie `YYYYMMDDHHMM` ...but no seconds

when I import `201111221420` into a `DATETIME` I get odd results like `2020-11-11`.

A `TIMESTAMP` format ignores the hours and minutes.

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: It looks like the code is assuming that you had YYMMDDHHMMSS format, and is substituting the current century for the 'missing' CC (so 201111221420 is treated as 2020-11-11 21:14:20 instead of 2011-11-22 14:20:00).  One fix would be to add the missing 00 to the end of the fields (edit the CSV file before importing it, maybe using [CSVFix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/)).  There may be other ways to achieve your required result.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Jonathan. I thought about tweaking the csv if I had to but that will become an ongoing chore. I would like to 'fix' it in MySQL if I can....

Comment: there probably easy solution, how you import CSV file in mysql? If you import csv file just one time you can do magic things with notepad++...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `str_to_date()` function like this:

Something like this should work:

```
load data infile 'myfile.csv'
into table xxx 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(@col1)
set 
  col1 = str_to_date(@col1, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
```

Comment: Thanks dnagirl, this worked well for me. All up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a large integer format, instead of a date format

Comment: Why would that help?  Can you demonstrate how it does help?

Comment: A large integer format would simply store the YYYYMMDDHHMM number without any sort of formatting. You could then format the number using code later. Just a thought; it may or may not be the best solution for your needs.